# Creating Table in Oracle, SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sqldatatypes, create-table

ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

I can't figure out what is going wrong with my dataypes and/or commas. Any help would be awesome. Thank you!

```
CREATE TABLE RIDERS
(RIDER_ID VARCHAR2(4) CONSTRAINT RIDERS_RIDER_ID_PK PRIMARY KEY,
FIRSTRIDER VARCHAR2(20) CONSTRAINT RIDERS_FIRSTRIDER_NN NOT NULL,
LASTRIDER VARCHAR2(20) CONSTRAINT RIDERS_LASTRIDER_NN NOT NULL,
ADDRESS VARCHAR2(25),
CITY VARCHAR2(15),
STATE CHAR(2),
ZIP VARCHAR2(15),
PHONE VARCHAR2(25)
DATEJOINED DATE,
AGENT_ID VARCHAR2(4) CONSTRAINT RIDERS_AGENT_ID_FK REFERENCES AGENTS(AGENT_ID),
TEAM_ID VARCHAR2(4) CONSTRAINT RIDERS_TEAM_ID_FK REFERENCES TEAMS(TEAM_ID));
```

Comment: You're missing a "," after: PHONE VARCHAR2(25)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
PHONE VARCHAR2(25)
```

There's your missing comma.

Answer (score 1):

You miss a comma after `PHONE`:

```
CREATE TABLE RIDERS
(RIDER_ID VARCHAR2(4) CONSTRAINT RIDERS_RIDER_ID_PK PRIMARY KEY,
FIRSTRIDER VARCHAR2(20) CONSTRAINT RIDERS_FIRSTRIDER_NN NOT NULL,
LASTRIDER VARCHAR2(20) CONSTRAINT RIDERS_LASTRIDER_NN NOT NULL,
ADDRESS VARCHAR2(25),
CITY VARCHAR2(15), 
STATE CHAR(2),
ZIP VARCHAR2(15),
PHONE VARCHAR2(25),
DATEJOINED DATE,
AGENT_ID VARCHAR2(4) CONSTRAINT RIDERS_AGENT_ID_FK REFERENCES     AGENTS(AGENT_ID),
TEAM_ID VARCHAR2(4) CONSTRAINT RIDERS_TEAM_ID_FK REFERENCES TEAMS(TEAM_ID));
```